# Memory leak in UIWebview when loading data content with url (WebCore::CachedResource::unregisterHandle)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a problem with `UIWebview`. When I'm loading data content with URL, The application has crashed. It occurs some time in the month, but I couldn't reproduce it. It occurs on client's device. The application run on iOS 7.1.

> ```
> 1. Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
> 2. Exception Subtype:    "KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS"
> 3. Thread 2 name: WebThread 
> 4. Thread 2 Crashed: 0 WebCore 0x38322b02
> WebCore::CachedResource::unregisterHandle(WebCore::CachedResourceHandleBase*)
>     + 110 1 WebCore 0x38322a8a WebCore::CachedResourceHandleBase::~CachedResourceHandleBase() + 14
>     2 WebCore 0x384b77fe
>     WebCore::MemoryCache::pruneDeadResourcesToSize(unsigned int) + 278 3
>     WebCore 0x38396aee WebCore::MemoryCache::prune() + 94"
> ```

---

The following is our source code:

```
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"cacheEnabled"]) {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:[defaults integerForKey:@"cacheSize"]];
} else {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"connectionURL"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [self.webView loadRequest:request];
     else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

In dealloc method:

```
[_webView setDelegate:nil];
[_webView stopLoading];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think main issue that you are loading request for webview not in main thread.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [self.webView loadRequest:request];
     else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

1/ You should change param queue to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`

2/ other bugs ( not relate with crash): you should check `response.statuscode == 200` before load webview :D